# Sending Email by PHPmailer without SMTP

Tags: phpmailer

I know that we could use PHPMailer to send an email without the need of SMTP. But I still don't understand how it is configurated.

1/ Can we set anything to "Email From"? If so then anybody could fake an email address and send it to anybody? If not what is the condition?

2/ What is the basic configuration that a Web server must have in order for it to work.

Sorry for my silly questions.

```
   <?php

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

       //Typical mail data
       $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
       $mail->SetFrom("britney@britneyspears.com", "Britney Spears");
       $mail->Subject = "My Subject";
       $mail->Body = "Mail contents";

       try{
         $mail->Send();
         echo "Success!";
       } catch(Exception $e){
         //Something went bad
         echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar.

see. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

> 1/ Can we set anything to "Email From"?

You can use `setFrom` . (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example)

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
```

> If so then anybody could fake an email address and send it to anybody?

uhhh... I think SMTP server has error.
PHPMailer use `$from`. maybe `$from` was setted by `setFrom` . (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php#L817)

> If not what is the condition?

If address doesn't set, I think error will occur. (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1185)

Comment: You can *try* to set a fake from address, but there is no guarantee that a mail server will accept or deliver it, especially if it leads to SPF failures. Some services ignore the from address completely, and always replace it with your account address (what you put in `Username`) - gmail does this. The key thing is not to try to do it. If you're making a contact form, follow the examples provided with PHPMailer.